# Dynamically Calculating a grouping aggregate

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have 3 columns Total, Count and Each
Each = total/count;

Using slickgrid and summing up the Each column is incorrect because of the weighted averages.

```
 Total     Count      Each
 4         2          2
 3         6          .5
---------------------------
 7         8          2.5 (incorrect )
```

7/8 = .875

```
 7         8          .875 (is correct if I take the sum(total) / sum(count) as an aggrigate)
```

I am using the

```
new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("Total")
new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("Each")
```

But how can I take the totals of those 2 and create a 3rd aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky and out of the usual way of dealing with the grid but I manage to do it with keeping some of your calculation inside global variables.

```
// global variables
var myGlobalCount = 0; 
var myGlobalTotal = 0;


function sumTotalsFormatter(totals, columnDef) {
    // keep the total inside the global variable 
    // this piece of code is new and outside of typical SlickGrid implementation
    switch(columnDef.field){
        case 'Count':   
            myGlobalCount = parseFloat(totals.sum[columnDef.field]);
            break;
         case 'Total':   
            myGlobalTotal = parseFloat(totals.sum[columnDef.field]);
            break;
    }

    // display as usual the Sum of whichever column that is
    // there is nothing new here, it's the simple SlickGrid sum display
    return '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'+totals.sum[columnDef.field]+'</span>';
}


function eachCalculation(totals, columnDef) {
    // VERY IMPORTANT.... The Each column has to come AFTER the other columns of Count & Total
    // the reason is simple we will use the global variables and they have to be filled prior to use them for calculation

    // do calculation with globale variables
    var eachTotal = myGlobalTotal / myGlobalCount;

    // display the calculation on the Title so that when you hover the total it will display calculation
    var titleText = "Total / Sum = " + eachTotal + " :: " + myGlobalTotal + " / " + myGlobalCount + " = " + eachTotal;

    return '<span style="font-size:9pt; font-weight:bold; color:gree" title="'+titleText+'">'+eachTotal+'</span>';
}

// Your columns definition will include your custom groupTotalsFormatter
columns1 = [
    {id:"Total", name:"Total", field:"Total", width:75, groupTotalsFormatter:sumTotalsFormatter},
    {id:"Count", name:"Count Part", field:"Count", width:100, groupTotalsFormatter:sumTotalsFormatter},
    {id:"Each", name:"Each", field:"Each", width:70, groupTotalsFormatter:eachCalculation}
];
```

I edited part of my code and didn't test with your code but it should work...try it out and let me know if you have issues... Good Luck

Comment: doesn't it answer your question??

Comment: Ya, Sorry I have been busy implementing other features but this is important. I haven't tested it, but I will award you the answer.

Comment: Happy it help you :)   just don't forget that this is a patch and isn't exactly how a SlickGrid should be implemented hehe